# How to map (String, Array[String]) to (String, String)

Tags: scala

I got a tuple ("banana", ("green", "yellow", brown")), but I want to have ("banana","yellow"), ("banana","green"), ("banana","brown").
How can I do that?

Comment: I would assume that tuple is inside another collection, right? If so, you need `collection.flatMap { case (key, values) => values.map(value => key -> value) }`

Comment: "How can i do that?" – You do it by writing a program which does that. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* narrow your problem down to a concise, focused, simple, short [mre] and ask a specific, focused, narrow question on [so].

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the question description is actually accurate.

```
val srcTup = ("banana", ("green", "yellow", "brown"))

val (resA
    ,resB
    ,resC) = ((srcTup._1, srcTup._2._1)
             ,(srcTup._1, srcTup._2._2)
             ,(srcTup._1, srcTup._2._3))
```

If, on the other hand, the question title is more correct:

```
val srcTup = ("banana", Array("green", "yellow", "brown"))

val res: Array[(String,String)] = srcTup._2.map(srcTup._1 -> _)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val (fruit, colors) = ("banana", Array("green", "yellow", "brown"))
colors.map((fruit, _))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```scala
source match {
   case (banana:String, fruits:List[String]) => fruits.map( (banana,_) )
}
```